# How to customize the footer magento 2 custom theme

Tags: magento2

I have create custom magento 2 theme based on magento blank theme. how can i customize the footer as show image below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `default.xml` file here in your custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Content for this file is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />

        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-top" before="-">
                <container name="footer_main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                    <container name="footer_main.content.row" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="row">
                        <container name="footer_main.content.logo" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-logo">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer.logo" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/logo.phtml"/>
                        </container>
                        <container name="footer_main.content.row.social" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer-links">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="footer.links" after="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/footer/links.phtml"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright.custom" template="Magento_Theme::html/copyright.phtml" after="footer_main.content.row.social" />
                        </container>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

After adding this content in your xml, you need to create template files.. We will create two new template files and we have used one default template file for copyright text.

So create first template file here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer/logo.phtml

Content for this file is ...

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>

<a href="external-link">External Link</a>
```

We will create another template file here.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer/links.phtml

Content for this file is ..

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 footer-links">
    <a href="test-1">Footer link 1</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 footer-links">
    <a href="test-2">Footer link 2</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4 footer-links">
    <a href="test-3">Footer link 3</a>
</div>
```

**Note : You can add your css to display that all blocks properly here..**

After adding above files you need to run below commands

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then you can see output as below attached Image..

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Is above solution helpful to you ?

Comment: I need to add copyright text under footer links also ..

Comment: I've updated this file there **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**, Please check this will work for you.

Comment: You need to do some designing changes there

Comment: Thanks Buddy, for appreciation!!

Comment: Thanks kishan your solution work for me ..